# Installing multiple versions of Qt library

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have installed QtSDK in windows and its Qt library version is 4.7.0.
Now i want to install Qt library version 4.8.2 for mingw and VS2008. How can i do this? How to introduce multiple versions to QtCreator?

Note : I have downloaded libraries from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install two versions of Qt and tell the application which to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962675/how-to-install-two-versions-of-qt-and-tell-the-application-which-to-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Just extract the libraries in a different location and set Qt Creator to use those as well. You can find how here: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html.

You can then choose which configuration to use to compile in the properties of each project.