# how to install Qt 4.8.4 with exsist Qt 5.1.1

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qmake

I have installed version of Qt 5.1.1, and I want to install Qt 4.8.5 because I need  to use NCreport library and this library is compatible only with Qt 4.8.5 and Qt 5.1.1 MVS.

How I can install Qt 4.8.5 with exist Qt 5.1.1 to be able to use NCRrepot library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install two versions of Qt and tell the application which to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962675/how-to-install-two-versions-of-qt-and-tell-the-application-which-to-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install those different two Qt major versions into different paths. You need to make sure when you would like to use the Qt 4 project, you need to have the relevant `qmake` executable in the path before the other one, or vica versa.

If you would not like to change the path dynamically, you can always specify the absolute path to the qmake executable for the one which you would like to use during that session.